# Enforce compiler settings via macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I am developing a framework which requires very strict compiler settings. Every time a new project is started and uses the framework, it must adhere to the settings (for example, warning level 4). Is there any way I can do that via macros and pragma statements? This will also allow me to do something like:

```
#ifndef NOT_USING_STRICT_SETTINGS
// All settings checks go here OR settings over-rides go here
#endif
```

This will benefit me as well in case I create a new project and forget to apply some settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of predefined macros from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx

These macros also allow checking for compiler directives.

Example:

```
#define USING_STRICT_SETTINGS defined(_MT) && defined(_OPENMP)
```

Comment: That is partially what I was looking for. What if I want to make sure that the user is not compiling with `Multi-threaded DLL` and force them to use `Multi-threaded` only?

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.80).aspx for the combinations of macros that are defined for each of those settings.